# How to configure docker to use /opt instead of /var

Tags: docker, centos7

Docker uses /var/lib/docker for storing images, how to configure docker to use /opt in centos ?

Comment: This isn't exactly a programming question. Probably belongs on [Unix.se]

Answer (score 2):

I can able to change the docker directory using following set of command's

1.Stop docker
**sudo systemctl stop docker**

2. create docker.service.d
   **sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d**

3.create docker.conf 
**sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf**

4.Add the docker.conf with following lines

**[Service]**

**ExecStart=**

**ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --graph=/opt/docker --storage-driver=devicemapper**

5.start Servicec
 **sudo systemctl daemon-reload**

**sudo systemctl start docker**

Now the docker is using opt/docker instead of /var/lib/docker

Answer (score 1):

You can configure docker daemon by option `--graph(-g for short)`. In CentOS the service is managed by Systemd, you can find the link of service unit file at `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service`, or the original place `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` and change the `ExecStart` line, like:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -g /opt
```

Then use `systemctl daemon-reload` to reload the changes, and `systemctl restart docker` to restart docker service.

Answer (score 0):

you need to  set the value of the graph parameter to your custom path, in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`
you can find it in: 
https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/#daemon-configuration-file

Comment: I am not find daemon.json in /etc/docker/ thanks @Mohammad Mahzoun

Comment: what is your docker version?